# Trying to upload a zip file using rsync in Windows does not work: rsync: connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: windows, rsync, file-server

I have got install rsync in Windows OS, now when I try to upload a zip file to a remote server, below error appears:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [Receiver=3.2.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

The rsync command I execute is the following:

```
rsync -avP -e "ssh -p 20300 -i C:\Users\myUser\.ssh\my_private_key" myZipFile.zip myusername@myserver:/path/to/main/folder/
```

**In my Windows System I don't have installed the Cygwin or similar, i am using the ssh that comes built-in in Windows operating system.
I am trying to find a solution that makes it work using the built-in ssh that comes from Windows without the needing of installing additional software like cygwin. So the answers provided in the community are not valid for me.**